# textbox data not being picked up

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Im using record sets to save data to a table, everything works fine apart from one line of code:

My code:

```
    'Save Data to Trigger_Data table
rec.AddNew
rec("CDP") = UCase(Environ("UserName"))
rec("Advisor") = AdvisorName
rec("Manager") = ManagerName
rec("Call_Duration") = CallDuration
rec("Account_Number") = AccountNumber
rec("Call_Reason") = CallReason
rec("Issue_Resolved") = CallResolved
rec("Repeat_Call") = RepeatCaller
rec("Satisfaction_Rating") = CallRating
Debug.Print "sss" & Comments
rec("Comments") = Comments
rec("Saved_Date") = Now
rec.Update
```

The section that is not recording data:

```
    Debug.Print "sss" & Comments
rec("Comments") = Comments
```

The spelling is correct - I have even deleted the textbox and created a new one just to be sure but the data is not being recorded for some reason

I have used debug.print and that is also showing as blank

Help

Comment: Have you tried using `Me!Comments.Value` instead of `Comments`? That's a more explicit way of referencing the value of the `Comments` control.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Tried this but still nothing showing. Must be something simple

Comment: Have you set `Option Explicit` at the top of your form module?

Comment: This is what I have at the top: Option Compare Database
Private lngNumOfSecs As Long

Comment: So... That's a no. Please add it, and explicitly declare all variables (except the controls since they are on the form). Read why [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?461140-Classic-VB-What-is-Option-Explicit-and-why-should-I-use-it)

Comment: If you use `Me.YourControl` you will get a list of the available controls from intellisense if the code is on the forms module. You don't need the .Value with that syntax as it is the default property. And as Erik said add Option Explicit to *All* your code modules.

Comment: @Minty just like you don't really need to add `Me.` (or `Me!` for that matter). I just like `Me!MyControl.Value` because it tends to generate a runtime error if the control is missing or of a type that doesn't support the `.Value` property, even if `Option Explicit` is off (which it should never be)